# pasarela de pagos paypal

Tags: jquery, html5, paypal

sinceramente nunca he tenido que hacer una pasarela de pagos ni con paypal ni tarjeta ni nada de esto y no sé que hacer.

Estoy intentando hacer que en la web, tras seleccionar varios productos en una ventana, en la siguiente me aparecen los productos seleccionados con su cantidad correspondiente (tipo carrito de la compra) y el total a pagar y me dicen que el método de pago tiene que ser paypal.

He creado un botón de paypal el cual lo he insertado a la web, pero no sé cómo tendría que hacer para pasar el precio total de los productos seleccionados para comprar a la pasarela de pagos de paypal.

**HTML del botón**

```
<div class="form-layout form-layout-2">

          <div class="row no-gutters">

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div id="myDiv_compra"></div>
              </div>
            </div> <!--col-12 -->

            <div class="col-md-9 mg-t--1 mg-md-t-0">
              <div class="form-group mg-md-l--1">
                <p class="precio-total">Total Priceing:</p>
              </div>
            </div> <!--col-4 -->

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group bd-t-0-force">
                <!--<p class="precio-total">4000 €</p>-->
                <p class="precio-total"><span id="spTotal"></span></p>
              </div>
            </div> <!--col-12 -->

          </div><!-- row -->
          <div class="form-layout-footer bd pd-20 bd-t-0" style="font-family: Dosis-Regular; font-size: 18px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="aceptarCondiciones" name="aceptarCondiciones" onChange="comprobar(this)"> To continue, you must accept the conditions
          </div><!-- form-group -->
          <div class="form-layout-footer bd pd-20 bd-t-0">
          <form action="https://www.paypal.com/" method="post" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="62NHHVTUB76D6">
            <input id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-info pos-btn" value="Submit Form" type="submit" border="0" name="submit" alt="Contratar" disabled>
            <!--<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">-->
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
          </form>
            <!--<button id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-info" disabled>Submit Form</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>-->
          </div><!-- form-group -->

        </div>
```

JQuery para sacar el Total

```
function sumar(valor) {
newvalor = parseFloat(valor); // Convertir el valor a un entero (número).

//Muestra el valor total de la suma de los precios de todas las especies
total = parseFloat(total) + newvalor;

// Colocar el resultado de la suma en el control "span".
document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total + " €";
```

}

Y lo que estoy intentando es pasar el valor de la variable **total** al paypal para que se realice el pago correspondiente, pero no sé cómo hacer para que cuando me envíe a PayPal me pase el valor del precio total.

Si me pudierais ayudar os lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias

Comment: espero que los datos que has puesto en el código no sean de tu cuenta de paypal real... (acces_stoken y otros)

Comment: Creo que esos datos son públicos de todos modos, ¿no? Al menos están en la parte del cliente y no del servidor.

Comment: Estos datos son los que me salieron al crear un el enlace para poner al botón para que me redirija al paypal para que el usuario pague a través de esta plataforma, pero al ser una url simple, no me recoge los valores de la compra, ya que te manda a la ventana donde uno tiene que poner todo, tipo de compra y lo que va a pagar